# How to classify input datatypes using buffered reader and exception handling?

Tags: java, types, input, ioexception

Assume the user inputs several values and the program has used the stringTokenizer to break the values up. The program would then try to parse the token and throw an error right? the error catch would output the datatype; 
This is a question given to a first year programming course so I'd rather not have a direct answer but more of a point in the right direction. The prof would like only two try...catch clauses, both of which were looking for NumberFormatException's.

Thanks in advance.

Original question:

> "Using exceptions and testing to classify keyboard input into one of
>   the eight primitive data types, or String."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will narrow down exactly what the input is in the order: boolean > char > double > float > long > int > short > byte

- Discard the "or String" part of the question, all Strings can be
  evaluated to a boolean value (see Boolean.parseBoolean(s)). So, your
  starting answer is "the input is a boolean", and keep going.
- Is the input exactly 1 character in length? If so, "the input is a
  character". Keep going regardless.
- Open a try block.
- Double.parseDouble(s). If there is no exception, "the input is a
  double", and keep going.
- Try each parse the input in the order given above.
- Open a catch block, catching NumberFormatException. The block will
  actually be empty, since what you really want is the finally block.
- Open a finally, in which you will return your answer.

Unless I'm missing somthing (entirely possible, since I've not writen the code), this gives you the "one" requirement, uses few exceptions, and takes advantage of exceptions to control flow.

Comment: Certainly, add your return after the empty catch.

Answer (score 0):

Final answer thanks guys

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
/**
 * Classifies input into primitive types or String
 * 
 * @author Suavelizard
 * @version Feb, 2012
 */
public class Classify 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Please enter some data (C-z or C-d to quit): ");
        String str = in.readLine();
        while (str != null) 
        {
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str);
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) 
            {
                String token = tokenizer.nextToken();

                // your code goes here!
                try{
                    long x = Long.parseLong(token);
                    if(x<= Byte.MAX_VALUE &&x>= Byte.MIN_VALUE){
                        System.out.println("Input is a Byte");}
                    else if (x<=Short.MAX_VALUE && x>=Short.MIN_VALUE){
                        System.out.println("Input is a Short");
                    }
                    else if(x<=Integer.MAX_VALUE && x>= Integer.MIN_VALUE){
                        System.out.println("Input is an Integer"); 
                    }
                        else{
                            System.out.println("Input is a Float"); 
                        }
                    }


                catch(NumberFormatException a){


                    try{
                        double x = Double.parseDouble(token);
                        if (x<= Float.MAX_VALUE &&x>= Float.MIN_VALUE)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Input is a Float");   
                        }

                        else if(x<= Double.MAX_VALUE &&x>= Double.MIN_VALUE)
                        {
                          System.out.println("Input is a Double");   
                        }


                    }
                    catch(NumberFormatException b){
                        if (token.length() == 1){
                         System.out.println("Input is a Character");  } 
                         else if(token.equalsIgnoreCase("true")|| token.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
                                         System.out.println("Input is a Boolean");  

                            }
                            else{                                        
                                System.out.println("Input is a String");  

                            }
                    }

                }
            }

            System.out.print("Please enter some data (C-z or C-d to quit): ");
            str = in.readLine();
        }
    } 
}
```